# Getting variable from another file

Tags: php, variables, include

How to pass the variables from one file to another, but only the variables, not the output of the file(content) . The `ob_start` isn't working for me, anything else?

Comment: not sure what you mean? showing some code may help

Comment: `include('yourfile')` to actually run the code and set the variables?

Comment: quite unclear what you want, there are a dozen ways to interpret this question.

Answer (score 4):

To pass a variable, you need to include your file

file1.php

```
<?php

$variable = "hello world";

?>
```

file2.php

```
<?php 
include ('file1.php')

echo $variable;
// hello world.

?>
```

and this is how you pass a variable from one file to another